# Insert TIMESTAMP with milliseconds in Oracle with cx_Oracle and Python 3.6

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

I need to insert a timestamp with milliseconds in an Oracle table with Python 3.6 and cx_Oracle 6.4.1. The insert is done okay but I am losing the milliseconds on the way.

The timestamp is passed as a datetime object. Any ideas how I could keep the milliseconds without making a to_timestamp() in the SQL itself? I would like to keep passing a datetime in the SQL transaction. I use executemany() as the idea is to insert multiple records at once.

```
import cx_Oracle
import datetime

conf = {
    'username': 'USERNAME',
    'password': 'PASSWORD',
    'tns': 'TNS'
}

d = datetime.datetime.now()
print(d)

db_conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conf['username'], conf['password'], conf['tns'], encoding='UTF-8', nencoding='UTF-8')
cursor = db_conn.cursor()

sql_insert = "INSERT INTO {} VALUES {}".format('timestamp_test', '(:1)')
cursor.prepare(sql_insert)
cursor.executemany(None, [[d]])
db_conn.commit()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not have the DB's current timestamp as a default value on your table column, then you do not have to insert it?

Comment: This looks to be [this issue reported on GitHub](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/161). One of the devs [commented](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/161#issuecomment-374269864) that `cx_Oracle.DATETIME` is used by default and that you could enforce TIMESTAMP by using `cursor.setinputsizes(cx_Oracle.TIMESTAMP)`